# Laravel 5.8: Can you help me with this problem about sessions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

I have an Online Store project written in Laravel 5.8 and in this project, I have set some sessions at the Controller, like this:

```
    $delivery_types = [];
    $conflicting = false;

    if ($foundOrder != null) {
        foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
            $product = Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first();

            array_push($delivery_types, $product->prd_delivery);

            $prds[] = [
                $product,
                $value->quantity,
                $value->price
            ];
        }

        $delivery_types = array_unique($delivery_types);

        if (in_array('iran_free_delivery', $delivery_types) && in_array('tehran_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
            $conflicting = true;
        }

        if (in_array(null, $delivery_types)) {
            Session::put('free' , 'no');
        } else if (in_array('iran_free_delivery', $delivery_types) && in_array('tehran_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
            Session::put('free' , 'city_country');
            //Session::put('iran' , '10');
            //Session::put('free_notfree' , '13');
        } else if (in_array('iran_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
            Session::put('free' , 'country');
        } else if (in_array('tehran_free_delivery', $delivery_types)) {
            Session::put('free' , 'city');
        } else {
            Session::put('free' , '0');
        }

    } else {
        $prds = [];
    }
    ...

 return view('frontend.shop.carts.index', compact('conflicting','...')'
```

And the problem is, whenever the `conflicting` re-submits at
`checkout.blade.php`, those session that were added before, still gets submitted.
However, it should not submit the OLD session.

So how to do this with Laravel?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guy..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unset the session variables after one attempt like this

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('name');
```

and for multiple data you can:

```php
$array_name = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_name);
```